# How can I search for a string by regex in the memory of another process?

Tags: c++, windows

I have found similiar question [How can I search for a string in the memory of another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231054/how-can-i-search-for-a-string-in-the-memory-of-another-process)

But in my case I need search by regex

regex pattern is "765611"

E.G.
I have typed in np++ "76511test45ras"

I need retrive in buffer 765611 and 4 char after this

How can I make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it exactly the same way as in the question you linked except instead of doing `memcmp` you run a regex match.