# C++ how to find last (offset - adress) used in processmemory with use readprocessmemory

Tags: c++, c, winapi

i use this code to `readprocessmemory`  :

```
  BOOL WINAPI ReadProcessMemory(
    _In_  HANDLE  hProcess,
    _In_  LPCVOID lpBaseAddress,
    _Out_ LPVOID  lpBuffer,
    _In_  SIZE_T  nSize,
    _Out_ SIZE_T  *lpNumberOfBytesRead
    );
char value[5]; 
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 6500);
{
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)105477, value, 5, 0);
}
```

### its work 100%

but i want to know how know last Offset used in processmemory - before i read it

see the picture : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukpZq.png)

the last offset in this processmemory is 7FFE0FFF - but how can i get it before i  read the processmemory

Comment: why vote my post - ?

Comment: How do you know it worked if you don't check the returned value?

Comment: This could change at any time. Memory is allocated and deallocation dynamically. What are you trying to do.

Comment: I mean, the above code looks just like an MSDN dump...

Comment: hi David Heffernan , i know its change - i just want to get the last offset

Comment: hi ThingyWotsit - i just try to make it sample and short

Answer (score 0):

Well it MAY work if you are absolutely sure that you CAN read the memory of the other process... anyway it is a quite dangerous method, there are much better IPC APIs to do these things!

Unless you are writing a debugger yourself... in fact ReadProcessMemory is cited here "Process Functions for Debugging" https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms680549(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: hi , "here are much better IPC APIs to do these things!" ?? like what ?

Comment: It depends on what you have to do... if you have to just exchange data between two processes, you have shared memories, pipes, sockets, and many others...

Comment: no no - i just want to get last ( used ) offset  of processmemory  - nothing else

Comment: but inside your process or inside another process??

Comment: another process - readprocess its work great ! now you know what i want - yes ? - see the picture  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukpZq.png

Comment: I repeat that unless you are writing a debugger or similar, you probably on the wrong way... anyway, you could try with VirtualQueryEx to inspect the allocated memory. See here https://www.codeproject.com/kb/threads/mdumpall.aspx and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372872/read-process-memory-of-a-process-does-not-return-everything

Comment: if you mean "si.lpMaximumApplicationAddress" - its for max address     >>>>>its not for last address used

Comment: no that is the maximum address for your system, like 2^32 if you have 4GB of RAM or something like that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372872/read-process-memory-of-a-process-does-not-return-everything where it uses info.RegionSize

Comment: ok tnx - i will see it - and try it and will back to you - tnx again man

Comment: please upvote and mark resolved if you found an answer :-)

Comment: i stil trying to understand how use it - if its work - i will mark it

Comment: can i use it to find string without check all process memory ? - how ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231054/how-can-i-search-for-a-string-in-the-memory-of-another-process  and  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878017/searching-for-every-occurrence-of-a-string-in-another-processs-memory

Comment: man - its long code to i want - i need to a small code to do what is ask - to can understand it . and what is VirtualQueryEx is do ???

Comment: just take the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231054/how-can-i-search-for-a-string-in-the-memory-of-another-process, you have a working solution. Smaller than this is not possible. Life of a programmer is hard, man.

Comment: ok i want to understand how code work ? - it is for find variable or find string or what ?? - what is VirtualQueryEx do ?