# How can I call a function from JAVA/JNA if I only know the offset from another function?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna, jnr

I know that in libaaa.so there is an exported (the symbol is in the text/code section) function obj1() at address 0x12345 from the start of the library.

`CLibrary libaaa = (CLibrary)Native.load("aaa", CLibrary.class);`

I want to invoke a function obj2() which I know to be at address 0x12444 from the start of the library OR the address of (obj1() + 0xff) (0x12444-0x12345=0xff)

The obj2() symbol is NOT in the text/code section, so I can only invoke it by its address (which I know.) I understand that I could use `Function.getFunction(new Pointer(funcAddr), 0, "utf8");` if I had the function's address, but I do not know what address JNA will load the library.

I can easily access the obj1() function (aaa.obj1()) that's trivial, but how could I access the aaa.obj2() function which is not in the text section, and thereby only referable from its offset in the library (or offset from another function in the text/code section.)

Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the scenario that creates this problem? What does this " which is not in the text section" mean?

Comment: @matt I do not have the source code of the library, and there is a function I need to call from java. Unfortunately I know the function's offset (from the start of the library, but there is not .text entry for it, so I can't simply invoke it by name. I suppose it would be workable if I knew which address the libaaa library is loaded.

Comment: Can you access the function from c? You could check the [Unsafe](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/misc/Unsafe.java) class, it lets you access native features and addresses.

Comment: From C I just use the offset from where the library is loaded.

Comment: If you can do it in C it seems reasonable that you could write a small wrapper that is the same function, but with a name so you can access it.

Comment: Why don't you get a pointer for obj1 and offset from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like if you get Function obj1,

```
Function obj1 = Function.getFunction(libraryName, functionName);
```

The Function Object *is* a pointer. Then you should be able to get the address of obj1, [Accessing JNA Pointer's peer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803909/accessing-jna-pointers-peer-value) so you would have the address and you can try to create a function based on that.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could compute the address of your second function, if you had the address of the first function. Is that right?

<strike>I've never tried it with `Function`s but I have a use case where I need to get the address of a `Callback` and what I'm doing to get that is to put it in a dummy `Structure` then read the structure's raw bytes.</strike>

Edit: forget that. It's only `Callback`s that don't let you access their address directly. You can easily get another Pointer/Function at an offset from a given Function. No need for workarounds.

Comment: I tried something along those lines, the closest I got was to get the address of the CLibrary object libaaa; but that's not the address of where the library is loaded, just the object itself.

Comment: From your question it sounded like "obj1" was in the symbol table (so you could create a JNA `Function` for it), and "obj2" was at a fixed offset from that. If that is not the case. I have no other ideas

Comment: you are right, obj1 is in the symbol table, but not obj2; but I know the offset of obj2 compared to obj1, that's how I can invoke obj2 from C.

Comment: ```You can easily get another Pointer/Function at an offset from a given Function. No need for workarounds.```

But how do I know which address the library is loaded at?

Comment: No idea about the library, but I don't understand why you need that when you can use the offset from obj1.